# How to solve an equation with a root in the divisor

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

The given function is $$f(x)=\frac{4-x^2}{3-\sqrt{x^2+5}}-6$$

Solve for $f(x) = 0$ What's x?

Comment: How have you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Nevermind, i got it. I was just really confused by the sqrt in the divisor. I multiplied the divisor, did ^2 and then solved it by substitution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first have to determine the domain of validity of this equation: we must have
$$3-\sqrt{x^2+5}\ne 0\iff x^2+5\ne 9\iff x\ne \pm 4.$$
 \begin{align}
\text{Now }\qquad f(x)=0&\iff\frac{4-x^2}{3-\sqrt{x^2+5}}=6\iff 4-x^2=18-6\sqrt{x^2+5}\\
&\iff x^2+14= 6\sqrt{x^2+5}\iff x^4 +28x^2+196=36x^2+180\\
&\iff x^4 -8x^2+16=(x^2-4)^2=0\qquad
\end{align}
Conclusion?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**
For $z\ne 3$, 
$$
\frac{4-x^2}{3-\sqrt{z}} - 6 = 0 \iff 4-x^2 = 6(3-\sqrt{z})
$$
can you solve for $\sqrt{z}$ and square both sides?

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:** Clear denominators, isolate the square root, square everything and hope for the best.